# Access value of account ID after passing it as parameter to Promise::new()

Tags: rust, nearprotocol, near

The following code generates an error:

```
let account_id = env::signer_account_id();
let amount = 10 * 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000;
Promise::new(account_id).transfer(amount);
env::log(format!("Sent {} NEAR to {}", amount, account_id).as_bytes());
```

```
    |
102 |         let account_id = env::signer_account_id();
    |             ---------- move occurs because `account_id` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
103 |         let amount = 10 * 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000;
104 |         Promise::new(account_id).transfer(amount);
    |                      ---------- value moved here
105 |         env::log(format!("Sent {} NEAR to {}", amount, account_id).as_bytes());
    |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

I am able to work around this by declaring another variable `same_account_id` which seems like a very bad way to get it to work.

```
let account_id = env::signer_account_id();
let same_account_id = env::signer_account_id();
let amount = 10 * 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000;
Promise::new(account_id).transfer(amount);
env::log(format!("Sent {} NEAR to {}", amount, same_account_id).as_bytes());
```

What's a better/*rusty* way to reference `account_id` after it has been passed as an argument in `Promise::new()`?

Comment: [The docs for `near_sdk::Promise` have examples](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.1/near_sdk/struct.Promise.html) using `&"accountIdLiteral".to_string()` which is more-or-less what you're doing already, fwiw.

Comment: @Dai: `&"accountIdLiteral".to_string()` did not work but `"accountIdLiteral".to_string()` did, since `Promise::new()` takes arguments by value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String doesn't implement `Copy`, and `Promise::new()` takes its argument by value.  This is why Rust says the value was moved and disallows you to use it later.

The simplest way to fix this is to give `Promise::new()` an explicit copy using `Clone::clone()`:

```
Promise::new(account_id.clone()).transfer(amount);
```

Alternatively, you could build the format string before giving `account_id` to the promise constructor, since the code that the `format!` macro emits won't take ownership of the string.  This prevents a needless copy of the string.

```
let msg = format!("Sent {} NEAR to {}", amount, account_id).as_bytes();
Promise::new(account_id).transfer(amount);
env::log(msg);
```

Comment: Gotcha, so I not too far off... I do need to make a copy if the format string is constructed after. Clarified things for me, thank you for the help!